# How to Debug script that is freezing without returning errors? (updating SQL tables - about 1.5 hour process)

Tags: php, debugging

I have a script that I can set to run on X items of data, process data from each item, and update a DB table with the processed data.

It is running successfully on 500 data items (About 2 minutes), and also on 2500
data items (takes about 10 minutes), but for 20,000 data items it freezes after about one hour (should finish in about 1.5 hours)

I can't post the code since script is too big and I'm not even sure it will matter, and in any way it works well when run time is shorter. the main question is how to debug such issue?

No PHP error log are showing (and they do show if something else is wrong), not seeing errors in MYSQL error log neither.

The script just stops updating its processing log, which means it does not insert anymore records to the table, even though it should. I can then only kill it and then I'll see error in my sql log like:

> [Warning] Aborted connection 192356 to db: 'db' user: 'user' host:
>   'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)

Comment: without code it's impossible to really have any idea what might be wrong

Comment: The client exceeded the max_allowed_packet for queries thats why is Aborted. 
https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/05/16/mysql-got-an-error-reading-communication-packet-errors/

Comment: @Oscar I manually aborted once I saw script froze. don't think it's related.

Comment: This happens always roughly after 1 hours. is there some config in server that limits the running time of one hour?

Answer (score 0):

you can use xdebug.
Xdebug is an extension for PHP to assist with debugging and development.
You can install Xdebug through PECL on Linux & macOS1. You can install Xdebug with PECL with:

> pecl install xdebug

When that is done, you still need to add the correct line to your php.ini

> zend_extension="/usr/local/php/modules/xdebug.so"